# Using Laravel Migrate how can I refresh a single database?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 databases and I used the following command:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

This cleared both databases and rebuilt the tables, however I'd like to do this only for a single database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `--database` option:

```
php artisan migrare:refresh --database=connectionName
```

For future reference, you can get help with arguments and options for any Artisan command by running:

```
php artisan help CommandName
```

Comment: Do I write connectionName as a string? Like "mysql" or without quotes?

Comment: Quotes are not necessary, if the connection name doesn't contain spaces or other characters that would need escaping, but you can use quotes if you like. This `--database=db1` is the same as this `--database="db1"`.